# Сортировка массива по алфавиту

Tags: массивы, сортировка, java

Есть строковый масcив имен

```
String[] s=new String{"Petya","Vasya","Fedya"};
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как отсортировать его по алфавиту?

Comment: можно прям код посмотреть? так ничего не понятно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: Вы были быстрее :-)

Comment: Уже пробовал.ругается на слово Arrays.

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: Ну как бы верно, но результат сортировки будет зависеть от выбранной локали :)